# Unit tests and Integration tests definitions & Maven

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, terminology, layer, definition

How do you define border between Unit testing and Integration testing?

Where is it exactly? In what part is layers testing ?

Related
[Terminology for integration tests which test each layer and the layers below it (Jenga tests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679212/terminology-for-integration-tests-which-test-each-layer-and-the-layers-below-it)
[What is the difference between integration and unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752/what-is-the-difference-between-integration-and-unit-tests)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use Apache Maven definition: those test that you run after you get your package are integration tests.

[Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

> - package - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable
>   format, such as a JAR.
> - integration-test - process and deploy the
>   package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can
>   be run

Then layers testing is part of Unit testing.